# How do I shift rows between data in APACHE POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

**PROBLEM**

I have an excel file which has a data in empty between rows. Like for example
[image: Excel]

How do I delete that space and shift the row up?

**What I've tried**

```
public static void removeRow(Sheet sheet, Row row) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();
    if(rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum){
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if(rowIndex == lastRowNum){
        Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if(removingRow != null){
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looping through this method but it does not shift up.

Comment: Doesn't  removing a row, make the next ones automatically shift up ?

Comment: @Berger yeah, but for some reason, mine doesn't work...... :(

Comment: What happens if you call `shiftRow` instead?